# Add HTTP header even if exception thrown

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I have created a middleware that add `HttpContext.TraceIdentifer` to the response header like so

```
public class TraceIdentifierHeaderMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public TraceIdentifierHeaderMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Trace-Identifier", context.TraceIdentifier);
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

And I put this middleware before any other middlewares in `Startup.cs`.

However, if an exception is thrown in a controller, this header won't be added. It seems that `Repsonse.Clear()` is called somewhere in the pipeline.

How can I ensure that this header is added?

Comment: Looks like Kestrel handles the unhandled application exception. I guess you have to catch the exception and handle the error response yourself.

Comment: @HenkMollema but then I won't be able to use middlewares like DeveloperExceptionPage

Comment: @Lucius Were you able to solve this ? Even `context.Response.OnStarting` doesn't work .

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a similar requirement to add the trace (GUID) ID to all the HTTP calls, even if there are exceptions.

And I was able to achieve this by using the OnStarting callback method. Adding the answer as it will be helpful for others

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("CorrelationId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });

    await next(context);
});

app.MapGet("/error", () => {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
});

app.MapPost("/success", () => {
    return "Created";
});

app.Run();
```

**GET Request with Exception:**

```
GET https://localhost:7095/error

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 29 Mar 2023 18:30:12 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
CorrelationId: dd3128cc-e37d-4e76-ad06-a7c9a437de02

System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at Program.<>c.<<Main>$>b__0_1() in F:\Learning\ResponseHeaderInHttpCalls\Program.cs:line 18
   at lambda_method1(Closure , Object , HttpContext )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.<>c__DisplayClass36_0.<Create>b__0(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Program.<>c.<<<Main>$>b__0_0>d.MoveNext() in F:\Learning\ResponseHeaderInHttpCalls\Program.cs:line 14
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Connection: close
Host: localhost:7095
User-Agent: vscode-restclient
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

**POST request with no exception**

```
POST https://localhost:7095/success

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 29 Mar 2023 18:33:57 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
CorrelationId: fa02d6a5-30cd-4a22-85c5-8fec2dd16e5e

Created
```

**Note:** If you are using the CORS policy, you need to expose this header in the policy or else you won't be able to access the header in the UI (Angular).

**Example:**

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.WithExposedHeaders("CorrelationId"); // can pass multiple header keys.
    });
});
```